# Android accessing secure REST services

Tags: javascript, android, rest

I have exposed the functionality over REST services, which only authenticated user can access. My clients are JavaScript based code running on browser  and Android clients. 
  Code is using google+ based authentication ( for both JavaScript and Android).  Now with browser client it is quite easy. As REST server can determine easily with passed access token, whether browser client is already authenticated or not. 
However for  android client; how REST server would know, that it is already authenticated. Is there any way to get the access code in android once user as has signed it. JavaScript client get access token, is there any token in case of android which can be used. 
    Yes I can implement oAuth (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent)  for android client without going with google+ sign-in directly. That would solve the problem, just wanted to check whether I can do without. Appreciate any help with this..

Comment: You need to create a session key valid for a particular time once user loged in. and you need to use that key to access REST services functionality.

Comment: How would REST service know 1) how would REST service would know that user has authenticated. Unless I encrypt a code with my cert once authenticated and REST server decrypt and check that it is valid one  2) How to differentiate it is coming from Web or Android App.. I can use something similar pointed out in previous bullet.. Are you suggesting something like that.. or I am getting it wrong.. Like to use existing authentication mechanism rather then inventing something new if possible :-)